# Explicit basis for homology of elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, elliptic-curves

Let $X=\{y^2=x^3+ax+b\}$ be an elliptic curve in $\mathbb{C}^2$ (so no point at infinity). Is it possible to write down explicitly a basis for the homology of $X$. By explicit I mean giving explicit maps $\sigma_i:[0,1]\to X$ such that the $[\sigma_i]$ in $H_1(X,\mathbb{Z})$ are a basis.

Comment: This is not terribly useful, but if $X$ is such that the real picture breaks up into an unbounded curve and an embedded circle, that circle (parametrized) will be one of the generators.